# How to get ID of update table from two databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating records from one table to one databae into another table of second database. 
which is working fine. i used this query.

```
"UPDATE table1.value1 , table2.value2 SET table1.value1.quantity = table2.value2.qty
WHERE  table1.`value1`.`sku` = table2.`value2`.`item` ";
```

And i need sku which number which are updated

i am using this query

```
SET @uids :=null;
"UPDATE table1.value1 , table2.value2 SET table1.value1.quantity = table2.value2.qty
WHERE  table1.`value1`.`sku` = table2.`value2`.`item` AND (SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) )

SELECT @uids;
```

What i am not able to get srring of sku's which are updated

Does anybody knows how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting idea.  I wonder if the following would work:

```
SET @uids := '';

UPDATE table1.value1 t1 join
       table2.value2 t2
       on t1.sku = t2.item
    SET t1.quantity = (case when @uids := concat_ws(',', fooid, @uids)
                            then t2.qty
                            else t2.qty
                       end);

SELECT @uids;
```

EDIT:

If the quantities are the same, you will not see an update.  Just fix the `join`:

```
SET @uids := '';

UPDATE table1.value1 t1 join
       table2.value2 t2
       on t1.sku = t2.item and t1.quantity <> t2.qty
    SET t1.quantity = (case when @uids := concat_ws(',', fooid, @uids)
                            then t2.qty
                            else t2.qty
                       end);

SELECT @uids;
```

Comment: and i have diff database too

Comment: @Hitu . . . It should not be returning `NULL` if the value of the variable is initialized to an empty string.  You should try this directly on the database first.  I think the issue may be in php, where you are trying to execute multiple SQL statements.

Comment: It should return all `fooid` that matches in the `join`.  If the quantities are the same, you will not see an update but you `fooid` will be added to the list.

Comment: yes, i am expecting this answer as a correct. Thanks

Comment: Whether or not values are counted as an update when the new value is the same as the old happens to differ among databases -- hence, it is something that I've learned over the years in working with multiple databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59807/discussion-between-hitu-and-gordon-linoff).